# Is it possible to set minTime and maxTime in react-native dataPicker?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, datepicker

I need a dataPicker to select a specific time interval e.g. I need to select intervals of 30 in 30 minutes between 1 and 2 hours. I want to show the dataPicker with the other hours disabled, allowing that the user select only the interval.

Currently, I'm using the [react-native-datepicker](https://github.com/xgfe/react-native-datepicker) to select the time, but I can't set *minTime* and *maxTime* in Android and *minuteInterval* in iOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass **minuteInterval**, **maxTime** and **minuteInterval** directly in props:

```
 <DatePicker
   minDate={today}
   maxDate={maxDate}
   minuteInterval={15}
 />
```